# Tkinter bind executes immediately when script is run

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I've laid out a frame, part of which is:

```
ticketID = IntVar()
ticketID.set(ticket)
ticketfield = Label(titleframe, text = 'Ticket : ')
ticketfield.grid(row=0, column=0)
ticketfieldentry = Entry(titleframe, textvariable=ticketID)
ticketfieldentry.grid(row=0, column=1)
ticketfieldentry.bind("<Double-Button-1>", searchforticket(ticketfieldentry.get()))
```

And a placeholder:

```
def searchforticket(ticket):
    searchforstring = "This would search for ticket %s" % ticket
    tkMessageBox.showinfo('Search by ticket', message = searchforstring)
```

`Ticket` is passed to the script at run time, or is assumed `None`. What I thought the above would do is create an `Entry` box that would display the ticket number, or could have one entered directly. After being entered, double clicking would bring up the `searchforticket` function.

However, when I run the script, `searchforticket` is run immediately, with whatever is being assigned to `ticket` and **then** after I click past the `tkMessageBox` is when the window containing the `ticketfieldentry` and everything else renders.

I am not seeing at all what could be causing this, but I assume it is something dead obvious to someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`searchforticket(ticketfieldentry.get()` cause immediate call. Change as follow:

```
ticketfieldentry.bind("<Double-Button-1>", lambda e: searchforticket(ticketfieldentry.get()))
```