# How to bind all frame widgets to <'Enter'> event

Tags: python, tkinter, binding, frame

I the following code I want to bind all frame1 items to <'Enter'> Event, but it does not work. I mean canvas.focus_set() does not take effect. How can I solve my problem?

```
for w in frame1.winfo_children():
    w.bind('<Enter>',canvas1.focus_set())
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21225198/tkinter-command-executed-automatically-when-binding-binding-not-acting-as-exp OR https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17205852/tkinter-bind-executes-immediately-when-script-is-run

Comment: Also you might want to check `bind_all` method

Comment: I checked all of your solutions but the problem exists again. My question is how to bind all frame items like check buttons to the same function event.

Comment: bind method needs method itself (callback method) not its return value.

Answer (score 2):

The [comment made by Lafexlos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53501843/how-to-bind-all-frame-widgets-to-enter-event#comment93873371_53501843) actually sends you in the right direction. When you do

```
w.bind('<Enter>', canvas1.focus_set())
```

you call `canvas1.focus_set()` and use the return value of this function call (which is `None`) to bind to the event. This isn't what you want, because now every time the event is triggered, `None` is executed instead of `canvas1.focus_set()`.

What you should do is pass a function reference to the `bind` function. The reference for calling `canvas1.focus_set()` is `canvas1.focus_set`. However, using

```
w.bind('<Enter>', canvas1.focus_set)
```

still doesn't work.
This is because the `bind` function passes an event object to the function it has been given, so it will call `canvas1.focus_set(event)` instead of `canvas1.focus_set()`. Because `focus_set` does not accept any arguments, this fails.

You can fix this in two ways. You could make an extra function, which does accept an event object and then calls `canvas1.focus_set()` without arguments, and then bind the event to this new function. The other option is to use an anonymous "lambda" function to basically do the same like

```
w.bind('<Enter>', lambda e: canvas1.focus_set())
```

This way the lambda function accepts the event object as `e`, but doesn't pass it to `focus_set`.

---

P.S. The `<Enter>` event is **not** the event that is triggered when you press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> button on your keyboard (that is `<Return>`). The `<Enter>` event is triggered whenever you move the mouse onto a widget and is accompanied by the `<Leave>` event for when you leave the widget with your mouse. This might be what you want, but it often leads to confusion.

Answer (score 0):

by using canvas1.bind_all which is the parent of frame1 I solved my problem. Thanks for all solutions.

Answer (score -1):

If there is any mistake I see you making it is likely you are not calling the write command for the `Enter` key. Hopefully, if you are attempting to do this on windows, you should rather use `Return`.

More like:

```
for w in frame1.winfo_children():
    w.bind('<Return>',canvas1.focus_set())
```

Comment: Why the downvote? does `Enter` work on your own windows machine? uh?

Comment: Use `Return` and rather than `focus_set()` you should bind to a function you created as stated earlier by @Lafexlos

Comment: `<Enter>` actually is a valid event and is fired whenever you enter a widget with your mouse. You're right in that `<Return>` is the event for pressing the Enter button, but whether that is or is not what the OP wants isn't clear from the question.

Comment: by using canvas1.bind_all which is the parent of frame1 I solved my problem. Thanks for all solutions.