# Is there a function to switch "Tab" and "Enter" button in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, development-environment, tkinter-entry

I'm creating a Gui with Tkinter with a lot of Entry widgets. However, I don't like the fact of clicking on Tab button to go from one entry to another. I would like it to be the Enter key that does this. Is there a function to make it happen ?? here is the list of all entries:

````
```python
entries = [self.entMath1, self.entMath2, self.entFran1, 
           self.entFran2, self.entSvt1, self.entSvt2, self.entEps1, 
           self.entEps2, self.entHg1, self.entHg2, self.entPc1, 
           self.entPc2, self.entAng1, self.entAng2, self.entPhi1, 
           self.entPhi2, self.entM1, self.entM2, self.entM3, 
           self.entM4]
for i in range(len(entries_1) - 1):
    entries_1[i].bind("<Return>", lambda e: entries_1[i].focus_set())
```
````

all these entries are placed with `place()` method.

Comment: Sure, you can use bindings to make just about any key do anything you want. You should read up on the `bind` method.

Comment: yes i'm using the `bind` method. But I'm not sure to make the fuction

Comment: You should provide a [mcve] that shows what you've tried.

Comment: I edited my post. You can take a look at it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/17677649/7432

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the `<Return>` key event on the `Entry` widget. Then in the bind callback, get the next widget in the focus order by `.tk_focusNext()` and move focus to this widget:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

for i in range(10):
    e = tk.Entry(root)
    e.grid(row=0, column=i)
    e.bind('<Return>', lambda e: e.widget.tk_focusNext().focus_set())

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: When I do this, It goes directly to the last entry. All the entries are created not simultaneously, but one by one, and placed with `place()` method.

Comment: It works fine for me.  Did you copy the example exactly? @OusmaneNgom

Comment: it's a little bit hard to reproduce the same code since I created the entries widgets differently. However, when i write the last line, it's said: 'Entry' object has no attribute 'focusNext'.

Comment: @OusmaneNgom: the function is named `tk_focusNext`, not `focusNext`.

Comment: oh I see. It works now !! Thank you a lot

Answer (score 1):

Have a read of this answer [binding enter to a widget](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53503513/2041317) for the difference between <Return> and <Enter>

From that, you can build something like

```
import tkinter as tk
top = tk.Tk()
frm = tk.Frame(top)
frm.pack()

# List of entries
seq = [None]
next = []
entmax = 5
for ii in range(entmax):
    ent = tk.Entry(frm)
    ent.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
    seq.append(ent)
    next.append(ent)

# Now set the entries to move to the next field
for ix in range(1, entmax, 1):
    seq[ix].bind('<Return>', lambda e: next[ix].focus_set())

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Did you do a for loop on the list?  I couldn't get that to work that is why mine has 2 lists.    @acw1668 might be a better solution.

Comment: I edited my post. you can take a look to the piece of code I have added. I used the `place()` method to place them (excuse my bad english, Im not a native !!)

Comment: Could you post the bind and focus_set code

Comment: I edited the post AGAIN. Have a look at it.